# Upload error in S3 for CSV, despite having "ESCAPE ACCEPTINVCHARS"

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

This seems to be a common problem with a common solution: Uploading a CSV via S3 and getting the `Missing newline: Unexpected character` error?  Just add `ESCAPE ACCEPTINVCHARS` to your COPY statement!

So I did that and still get the error.

My CSV looks like this:

```
email, step1_timestamp, step2_timestamp, step3_timestamp, step4_timestamp, url, type
fake@email.gov, 2015-01-28 12:1I:05, 2015-01-28 12:1I:05, NULL, NULL, notasite.gov, M Final
wrong@email.net, 2015-01-28 12:7I:19, NULL, NULL, NULL, notasite.gov/landing, M
```

I successfully upload in S3 and run the following COPY

```
COPY <my_table> FROM 's3://<my_bucket>/<my_folder>/uploadaws.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<my_id>;aws_secret_access_key=<'
REGION 'us-west-1'
DELIMITER ','
null as '\00'
IGNOREHEADER 1
ESCAPE ACCEPTINVCHARS;
```

My error code:

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x6e found at location 4194303
```

The first characters of the error:

:05,,,,,M Final
xxxx@yyyyy.com,2015-01-28 12:1I:05,,,,,M Final
xxx.xxx@yyyy.com,2015-01-28 12:1I:05,,,,,M Final
xxxx

Comment: As added info (noise?).  Everytime I make an attempt and read the error I get a different Unexpected character (eg 0x6e, 0x30, 0x67 etc) and a different location (eg 4194303, 6508, 9580).  But it's always on line number 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your file probably just needs a newline at the end of the very last row.

`ACCEPTINVCHARS` won't help as it for files that contain invalid UTF8 codepoints or control characters.

`ESCAPE` is for loading embedded quotes in files with quoted data. Your file would have to be specially prepared for that.